# Load C# Dataset (as XML) into Delphi (ADODataset or ClientDataSet)

Tags: c#, xml, delphi, dataset, delphi-7

I need to load C# dataset into Delphi dataset

As long as i know, C# access Database through its internal SQLQuery function, and able to save content as .xml files.

Is it possible to load dataset contents from those files into program written on Delphi ?

What is simplest way to convert C# XML into any of Delphi XML ?

Comment: What version of Delphi are you using? That will greatly determine what you can or cannot use

Comment: Have you looked up the XmlMapper utility and TXmlTransformProvider object in the Delphi OLH?

Comment: XmlMapper Utility cannot be uses runtime

Comment: If that XML is stored by ADO on your C# side, you can try [`this code`](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=1498) to load it in Delphi.

Comment: "XmlMapper Utility cannot be uses runtime" - Maybe not, but seeing as it is written around TXmlTransformProvider and TClientDataSet components, that is hardly an obstacle because you can use those components yourself!  Or, do what @TLama suggests.

Comment: Let me get this straight! You are trying to use some C3 program to export data from some database and store it in XML form. And then on Delphi side you want to import that data from XML form into another database? Wouldn't it be easier to access the same database that C3 access directly from Delphi application? Now if the database C3 acces is a custom database made with something similar as Typed Files in Delphi directly accessing that data would not be so easier bit is still doable if you know the exact data structure.

Comment: You use the XmlMapper utility to create a *transformation* schema XTR file once. then you load the variable *data* in run-time using that XTR. see this article: [Use ADO.NET datasets in Delphi](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/28631)